# C++ Quick-sort is not sorting the array properly

Tags: c++, quicksort

Hello i got an array of 10 elements. [0...9].
Inside of it there are numbers - [0,1,2,...,8,9].
I'm trying to sort the array descending but instead of [9,8,...,2,1] i am getting [ 4  3  2  1  0  5  6  7  8  9  ].

My quicksort code.

```
void q_n(int arr[], int left, int right) {
    int i = left, j = right;
    int tmp;
    int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

    /* partition */
    while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] > pivot)
            i++;
        while (arr[j] < pivot)
            j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    };

    /* recursion */
    if (left < j)
        q_n(arr, left, j);
    if (i < right)
        q_n(arr, i, right);
}
```

Anyone can help me with this ? ;s

Comment: I love such titles `Quick-sort is not sorting the array properly`. No, quick sort sorting array properly, your implementation of quick sort does not.

Comment: @Lashane, even his implementation is sorting array **properly** - according to the code.

Comment: I love such answers too. Any ideas what to change? If not, do not answer. btw. that is the only change i did to original quicksort(ascending order)  while (arr[i] > pivot) ,  while (arr[i] < pivot)

Comment: @Jim.D I don't see any answers yet, comments - yep

Comment: @SergeyA looks so, so problem is somewhere outside of this code

Comment: I have tried your code here:http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jKjr4eM7n293qeqM and I am getting the answer properly, I didnt gone through your code.

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem. So stupid. Dont know why this happened.
The problem was not in the qsort code but in the calling function.

```
q_n(array, 0, sizeof(int));
```

changed to:

```
q_n(array, 0, 9);
```

and worked perfectly.

Answer (score -3):

If you don't have to implement quick sort, use the built in one:

```
qsort(A, n, sizeof(int), compare_function);
```

where `A` is an array of `int`, n is the number of elements in the array and you have to specify a compare function:

```
int compare_function(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2)
{
    int tptr1 = *(int*)ptr1;
    int tptr2 = *(int*)ptr2;

    return tptr2 - tptr1;
}
```

use `return tptr1 - tptr2;` for ascending order and `return tptr2 - tptr1;` for descending

EDIT:
I just copy-pasted the previous code and didn't noticed the `int-float` mistake. Here is a complete example how `qsort` works for those who want to use it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare_function(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return *(int*)a - *(int*)b; //ascending
    //return *(int*)b - *(int*)a; //descending
}

int main()
{
    int A[100];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
    {
        A[i] = rand();
    }

    qsort(A, 100, sizeof(int), compare_function);

    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\n", A[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What the hell is that supposed to mean? `float tptr1 = *(int*)ptr1;`

Comment: @SergeyA I suppose it tries to avoid integer overflow if one argument is MIN_INTEGER and another one is MAX_INTEGER

Comment: @Lashane, yes, but loosing meaningful precision on the go.

Comment: And then casting the result back to an integer looses anything that was gained by avoiding the overflow/underflow.

Comment: it means that the compare function takes a const void pointer, and you have to tell what kind of variable it has to deal with

Comment: @AJNeufeld actually no, basically only sign of result makes sense for this case. So as soon as casting to int will preserve sign - it will work

Comment: take a look at the reference page before you talk: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/

Comment: @SergeyA we don't need precision here, we need sign of operation

Comment: are *all* `int`s mapped to distinct `float`s?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, of course not. Physically impossible - compare max float and max int :), take into account the fact that they use (on a typical platform) same number of bits and you have your answer.

Comment: @Lashane, he will be getting incorrect results. There are more integers than whole floats, and two different integers will be represented as same floats, giving incorrect result for the comparison.

Comment: @Lashane `+0x7fff0000 - (-0x00001000)` gives you a negative result, not the desired positive number that should be returned given that `+0x7fff0000 > -0x00001000`.  See http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jQSnm1kUXteeBNL9